# maximum no of integer items that can be created by an int vector

Tags: c++

I have an integer vector

```
std::vector<int> somevec
```

The limits of int can be queried via

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::min() and std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Can I create a vector whose size exceeds std::numeric_limits::max() i.e.

```
can somevec.size() > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` uses a `size_type` member for indexing, which is usually not the same type as `int`. Thus, use:

```
std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max()
```

So in theory, yes, it's possible to have `somevec.size()` be larger than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

However, `std::vector` also has a maximum size which is usually smaller than this amount, you can query it like this:

```
somevec.max_size();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have this problem when using HDF5 library which disappears when long is used in place of int. Is there a way of increasing the limit given given by max_size() or is it absolute?

Comment: @SumanVajjala You can't change it, but a container like `std::deque` or `std::list` usually have much higher `max_size`s.

Comment: I've a integer vector which can hold 2195543407 elements. But for some reason I get an error for just 22870257 elements. Probably has to do with HDF5 library

Comment: @SumanVajjala From what I understand, `max_size` is only an estimation of the upper bound.  You can get a `std::bad_alloc` thrown before you reach it.

Comment: @ Pubby: Thanks a lot for your answers :) When in theory, a vector can take more number of elements then why does a maximum size exist (assuming one has sufficient RAM)? Any insight into this?

Comment: @SumanVajjala The maximum size usually corresponds to the maximum contiguous allocation possible. The `size_type` usually corresponds to the size of the address space.